# Reduce left text padding in too-small table cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

Given the following table with the column type C defined so that it has (small) fixed width and supposedly centered text, how can I make it so that the text is *actually* centered? None of the cell contents will have a length greater than 3 digits with a decimal point.

Using `\setlength\tabcolsep{}` doesn't work and setting the column type to `c` has the columns too wide, though `p` looks essentially identical as the cells are too small to have actually centered text. Using `@{}` removes all padding along the left side of the cell.

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|r||C{.31cm}|C{.31cm}|C{.31cm}|C{.31cm}|C{.31cm}|C{.31cm}|C{.31cm}||}
    
    \cline{1-8}
        \small ---- & \footnotesize0.9 & \footnotesize0.92 & \footnotesize0.99 & \footnotesize1.0 & \footnotesize\textbf{***} & \footnotesize\textbf{***} & \footnotesize\textbf{***}\\
    \cline{1-8}
    
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You  didn't set any value for `\tabcolsep`?

Comment: Why would you want to use an `m` column identifier for something that is not paragraph based?

Comment: Bernard, I tried a few different values for ```\tabcolsep``` but none solved the centering issue.
Steven, a ```p``` would work just as well, but the issue persists.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you specified a width for your `X` type columns. You don't have to: the width of cells is determined by the package, on the basis of the total width.

Comment: I need all the cells/columns to be uniform in width.

Comment: you are not using tabularx at all, there are no X columns so tabularx has no mechanism to achieve the specified total width.

Comment: `\small ----` makes an emdash followed by a hyphen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about one of the following two suggestions?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{6pt}}r@{\hspace{6pt}}||*{7}{>{\footnotesize}C{\dimexpr.31cm+12pt}|}|}
    \cline{1-8}
        \small --- & 0.9 & 0.92 & 0.99 & 1.0 & \textbf{***} &  \textbf{***} & \textbf{***}\\
    \cline{1-8}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mywidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\mywidth}{\widthof{\footnotesize 0.99}}
    \begin{tabular}{|r||*{7}{>{\footnotesize}wc{\mywidth}|}|}
    \cline{1-8}
        \small --- & 0.9 & 0.92 & 0.99 & 1.0 & \textbf{***} &  \textbf{***} & \textbf{***}\\
    \cline{1-8}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That first one worked great, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|r||*{7}{C|}|}
    \hline%\cline{1-8}
        \small --- & \footnotesize 0.9 & \footnotesize 0.92 & \footnotesize 0.99 & \footnotesize 1.0 & \footnotesize\textbf{***} & \footnotesize\textbf{***} & \footnotesize\textbf{***}\\
    \hline%\cline{1-8}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
    width = 0.55\textwidth,
    colspec={|r||X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]||},
    column{1} = {font=\small},
    column{2-5} = {colsep=3pt,font=\footnotesize},
    column{6-8} = {colsep=3pt,font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
  }
    \cline{1-8}
    --- & 0.9 & 0.92 & 0.99 & 1.0 & *** & *** & *** \\
    \cline{1-8}
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]